# Java Error: constant string expression required

Tags: java, switch-statement, constants

i have 2 Java classes:

```
public abstract class IconNames {
/**
 *
 */
public static final String ButtonFett = java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle("recources/buttonproperties").getString("fett");
}
```

and

```
public class EditorPanelActionListener implements ActionListener{
.
.
.
String buttonText = e.getActionCommand();
switch(buttonText)
    {
        case IconNames.ButtonFett: //Error: constant string expression required
            replace(XmlTags.BOLD);
            break;
    }
 .
 .
 .
 }
```

The EditorPanelActionListener fire the error "constant string expression required", whats the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Short answer: The cases of a `switch` statement must be compile time constants. Your variable can only be evaluated at runtime.

Comment: can e.getActionCommand() return enum instead of a String?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not mix up program logic and user interface texts. The action command is a property distinct from the text shown and only defaults to the shown text if not set explicitly.

```
public abstract class IconNames {
  public static final String ButtonFett_CMD = "DO-BOLD";
  public static final String ButtonFett_TXT = java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle("recources/buttonproperties").getString("fett");
}
```

…

```
JButton b=new JButton(IconNames.ButtonFett_TXT);
b.setActionCommand(IconNames.ButtonFett_CMD);
```

…

```
String buttonText = e.getActionCommand();
switch(buttonText)
{
    case IconNames.ButtonFett_CMD: // user language independent
        replace(XmlTags.BOLD);
        break;
}
```

This works for subclasses of `AbstractButton` which includes menu items as well. If you are dealing with Action implementations directly (which I doubt seeing your switch statement) you should differentiate between the `Action.NAME` and `Action.ACTION_COMMAND_KEY` property.